# json update only one value if its a new value in the json

Tags: angularjs, json, auto-update

This was my previous solution to get info from a json but I want to do it so that I print out a table and show the info, and only update the changes in the code, but not all in the table. Right now, when one person update it changes for all.

```
app.controller('list', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
  $interval(function () {

    $http.get('http://localhost/mvcang/list_it/sell/SWISH')
    .then(function(data) {
      if($scope.phones != data.data){
        data = data.data;
        $scope.phones = data;

      }
    });
  }, 500);

});
```

So, it should look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr> 
   <td>value</td> 
   <td>value2</td>
   <td>value3</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>value</td> 
   <td>value2</td>
   <td>value3</td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

If a value in number one value is changed just update that, but not the whole thing, and if its something new, then add it to the list in the order it prints out.

```
i = 0;
var arr = this.old.split(', ');
angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(value, key){
  if(arr[i] != value.data.profile.username ){
    this.customHtml +=  '<li>' + value.data.profile.username + '</li>';
    this.old += ', '+value.data.profile.username;
  }
  i++;
 });
```

Here's something I thought of but can't integrate, or rethink the whole.

Comment: Of course it will overwrite the whole thing, you set the entire data set on every http call. `$scope.phones != data.data` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: read before you comment my previous solution

Comment: it like a remake of the code

Comment: It would be better if you can just request changes in the list, and then update accordingly. You could do something more inefficient and just filter through the new array and find the original array object and update it, but, like Seiyria said, `$scope.phones != data.data`.

Comment: its the old code i renew it stop write things that dont matter i write my old code so u can se the structur in the code so you know what type of varables i allready have